# How to use opacity when not use rgba color in css?

Tags: html, css

If i use rgba color i can use like this. `background-color=rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`. But I am not using RGBA color. I just use `background-color:#4D4D4D;`. I need this because if i use `opacity:0.5` it will effect to all the component of the div. So how can i use opacity with this color code ?

Comment: Why not just use `rgba`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills it difficult to find the colors .

Comment: A simple [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+hex+colors+to+rgb&oq=convert&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59l3j0j69i61.2694j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) search will yield you thousands of results. Simply take the RGB value it gives you and determine the opacity you want as the a. Simple enough...

Comment: A very short google search revealed this tool: http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/

I'm pretty sure that is your best bet, since opacity disqualified for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Since the question has been clarified, the answer is you have to use RGBA. Just hit up a site like http://www.rgbtohex.net/hextorgb/ to do the conversion from HEX to RGB.

> You entered Hex code: #4D4D4D which converts to the following in RGB: R: 77 G: 77 B: 77

---

`opacity:0.5`; should work and has great cross browser support: http://caniuse.com/css-opacity

Comment: no if i set like u said for a div then all the components of the div will affect the transparency .

Comment: Your question doesn't mention anything like those requirements.

Comment: @Harshana if you don't want to affect the components of the div then the correct way is with rgba only

Comment: are u sure ? is that the only way :O ?